# Trouble simplifying the pdf of minimum exponentially distributed r.v.

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

Given the following: $ X_i \sim EXP(1, \eta) $

Asked: show that $Q=X_{1;n}-\eta$ is a pivotal quantity.

My approach:

$\ \ \ f(x)=e^{-(x-\eta)} \Rightarrow F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(t-\eta)}dt=-e^{-(x-\eta)} \\$
$\ \ \  f_{X_{1;n}}(x)=nf(x)[1-F(x)]^{n-1}=n\cdot e^{-(x-\eta)} [1+e^{-(x-\eta)}]^{n-1} $

My question is: **how to simplify this further?**

According to my TA, the correct answer should be: $ f_{X_{1;n}}(x)=n\cdot e^{-n(x-\eta)}  \text{ with constraint } x\geq \eta$
But I don't see how to go from my expression to this expression. Hence: where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake. $F$ is always positive!
$$f(x) = e^{-(x - \eta)} \quad x \geq \nu$$
So
$$F(x) = \int_\eta^x e^{-(t - \eta)} dt = 1 - e^{-(x - \eta)} \quad x \geq \eta $$
So we have
$$ 1 - F(x) = \ldots$$
you can take it from here.

Comment: aah of course. Thanks! What a stupid mistake :) Merci beaucoup!